# Select all attr in a class

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to select and disable all input attribute in a class. I am able to disable all radio buttons but thats not what I want. any help appreciated, Thanks.

```
<div class="sectionClass sectionA"> 
    <input type="radio" value="week">week<br>   
    <input type="radio" value="month">month<br> 
    <input type="radio" value="year">year<br>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="sectionClass sectionB"> 
    <input type="radio" value="A">A<br> 
    <input type="radio" value="B">B<br> 
    <input type="radio" value="C">C<br>
</div>
```

my js:

```
$("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
```

[link to my code](https://jsfiddle.net/v42g1ynz/)

Comment: Ok, so there are only radio buttons in your html snippet.  So what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQUERY

```
$(".sectionA > input").attr('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$(".sectionB > input").attr('disabled', true);
```

Snippet:

```js
$(".sectionA > input").attr('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sectionClass sectionA"> 
    <input type="radio" value="week">week<br>   
    <input type="radio" value="month">month<br> 
    <input type="radio" value="year">year<br>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="sectionClass sectionB"> 
    <input type="radio" value="A">A<br> 
    <input type="radio" value="B">B<br> 
    <input type="radio" value="C">C<br>
</div>
```

Comment: sure! i did a few times, but it wont allow me I have to wait 10 mn. but surely, you get a check mark. thanks again

Comment: by the way, how do I style that disable radio buttons? it looks ugly

Comment: I'm not really good at styling radio buttons so I normally just follow this guide:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp